# Can I create a page template from a plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a payment processing plugin and I need several custom pages so I am wondering is there a way to generate them from the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate pages in WordPress programatically by interfacing with the database.

This example creates a new page called "Books"

```
function books_page_setup() {
    global $wpdb, $user_ID;
    if ( get_site_option('books_page_setup') != 'complete' && is_site_admin() ) {
        $page_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE post_name = 'books' AND post_type = 'page'");
        if ( $page_count < 1 ) {
            $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO " . $wpdb->posts . " ( post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, to_ping, pinged, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, post_content_filtered, post_parent, guid, menu_order, post_type, post_mime_type, comment_count ) VALUES ( '" . $user_ID . "', '" . current_time( 'mysql' ) . "', '" . current_time( 'mysql' ) . "', '', 'Books', '', 'publish', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'books', '', '', '" . current_time( 'mysql' ) . "', '" . current_time( 'mysql' ) . "', '', 0, '', 0, 'page', '', 0 )" );
        }
        update_site_option('books_page_setup', 'complete');
    }
}
```

[Interfacing With the Database INSERT rows](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_rows)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but would it be possible to insert php code in a page that way? I think that I need a way to programatically create a page template in order to insert php code. I may be wrong, though.